# Left join and Group how to join the tables

Tags: sql

What I need is to join the tables and pull the name of the series and its due seasons

`tbl_seriados`

```
serie_id | serie_slug | serie_nome
    1    |  slug-01   |   slug 01
    2    |  slug-02   |   slug 02  
    3    |  slug-03   |   slug 03
```

`tbl_temporadas`

```
temp_id  | serie_id | serie_slug | temp_nome
    1    |     2    |   slug-02  |    xxx 1
    2    |     2    |   slug-02  |    xxx 2
    3    |     3    |   slug-03  |    xxx 1
```

in that my select is looping for each result, how do I use `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_seriados LEFT JOIN tbl_temporadas
ON tbl_seriados.serie_id = tbl_temporadas.serie_id
```

I want the following result

my url (will be dynamic)

`www.mysite.com/`**slug-02**

```
________________________
|serie_nome: slug 02   |
________________________
|temp_nome: xxx 1      |
|temp_nome: xxx 2      |
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: (1) Edit your question and show the results you want.  (2) Explain why you want `group by`.  It is not obvious.  (3) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (4)  Explain what "due seasons" has to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't have to use `GROUP BY`, you should use `WHERE`:

for `www.mysite.com/slug-02`:

```sql
SELECT temp_nome FROM tbl_seriados LEFT JOIN tbl_temporadas
ON tbl_seriados.serie_id = tbl_temporadas.serie_id
WHERE serie_slug='slug-02';
```

results:

```
temp_nome
____________
|xxx 1      |
|xxx 2      |
```